# Issue with sortable() and how to limit number of sortable items using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two things to ask for. Here is my reference code: http://jsbin.com/axegem/19/

**Issue:** When I drag and drop divs within one parent, every thing is fine. If I drop the element onto other parent, I see my Dropped() event is called twice. To make it more clear, if I drop **DIV 3** after **DIV 6** (with respect to my sample code), I see the alert coming twice. Why is this so? This is supposed to be coming once.

**Question:** Once the above issue is solved, I need to limit the number of childs to 4. Lets say I have **DIV 4, DIV 5, DIV 6** in my second parent. If I try to drop **DIV 3** after **DIV 6**, **DIV 3** must come back to its original position. How can I achieve this using JQuery?

Thanks..

Comment: Per jQuery UI: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update -- It's firing once for the sorting of the left-most div and once for the sorting of the target div.

Comment: How can I make it fire this event only once?

Comment: I am done with my first issue. Now my problem is how I can limit the number childs to 4. Any help is greatly appreciated.